# Dimensional Error in CNN

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning

I'm trying to create a CNN for distinguishing between cats and dog
The data I have Taken from Kaggle
I m facing error after flattening the layer.

model Parameters are as follows:

```html
IMG_SIZE=55

filter_size = 5;
no_of_filters1 = 16;
no_of_filters2 = 32;
no_of_filters3 = 64;
classes=2
x=tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE,1])
y=tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,classes])

w1= weights([filter_size,filter_size,1,no_of_filters1])
w2= weights([filter_size,filter_size,no_of_filters1,no_of_filters2])
w3= weights([filter_size,filter_size,no_of_filters2,no_of_filters3])
wfc=weights([no_of_filters3,625])-ERROR
w_0=weights([625,classes])
```

My CNN Model:

```html
def model(x,w1,w2,w3,w4,w_o):

    #Layer1
    layer1= tf.nn.conv2d(x,w1,strides=[1,1,1,1],padding='SAME')
    layer1= tf.nn.relu(layer1)
    layer1=tf.nn.max_pool(layer1,ksize=[1,2,2,1],strides=[1,2,2,1],padding='SAME')

    # Layer2
    layer2 = tf.nn.conv2d(layer1,w2, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1],
                          padding='SAME')
    layer2 = tf.nn.relu(layer2)
    layer2 = tf.nn.max_pool(layer2, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1],padding='SAME')

    layer3 = tf.nn.conv2d(layer2,w3,
                          strides=[1, 1, 1, 1],
                          padding='SAME')
    layer3 = tf.nn.relu(layer3)
    layer3 = tf.nn.max_pool(layer3, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1],padding='SAME')

    layer_shape= layer3.get_shape()
    num_features = layer_shape[1:4].num_elements()

    fc_layer=tf.reshape(layer3,[-1,num_features])
    fc_layer=tf.nn.relu(fc_layer)

    ouput_layer= tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(fc_layer,w4))
    logits= tf.matmul(ouput_layer,w_o)

    return logits
```

Error Being Raised is :

> ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 1024 and 64 for 'MatMul' (op: 'MatMul') with input shapes: [?,1024], [64,625].

Kindly Guide me.

Comment: Why you put wfc as 625? As you put the filters, the image size changes. And the change is proportional to filter size. So you need to do relevant calculation to get the proper weight sizes.

Comment: @Beta can you please explain me the calculations?

Comment: check this [https://adeshpande3.github.io/adeshpande3.github.io/A-Beginner%27s-Guide-To-Understanding-Convolutional-Neural-Networks-Part-2/]. It gives the formula for calculating the dimension based on filter specifications.

Comment: Sir its showing - File not found

Comment: https://adeshpande3.github.io/adeshpande3.github.io/A-Beginner%27s-Guide-To-Understanding-Convolutional-Neural-Networks-Part-2/

Answer (score 1):

For Fc layer you need to have match the `weights` first dimension with the input last dimension, in this case, its `1024`

```
no_filters_in = 1024
wfc=weights([no_filters_in, no_of_filters3])
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to take the feature map size into account. Suppose the shape of layer3 is (4,4,no_of_filters3), where 4x4 is the feature map size. Then the shape of fc_layer is (4x4xno_of_filters3, 1). When you execute "tf.matmul(fc_layer,w4)", the right shape of w4 should be (4x4xno_of_filters3, 625).